# Vb.net System.IO.StreamReader Empty path name is not legal

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I have a fault with System.IO.StreamReader.

```
Public Class Project

    Dim merah As Integer
    Dim File_Directory As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(File_Directory.FileName)
    Dim Text_LineByLine As String

Private Sub BrowseFile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BrowseFile.Click



    File_Operations()
    'Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
    Default_Operations()
    MessageBox.Show(Text_LineByLine)
    'Loop

End Sub

Sub File_Operations()
    File_Directory.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    File_Directory.Filter = "All files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If File_Directory.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        BrowserPath.Text = File_Directory.FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

When the program starts, The faultis  'Empty path name is not legal.'

How to solve this fault?

Thanks for any helping.

Comment: You cannot use *As New* for the objReader member, it gets created too soon.  This is indeed not terribly intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

You write:

```
Dim File_Directory As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(File_Directory.FileName)
```

but you need to use

```
Dim File_Directory As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
If File_Directory.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(File_Directory.FileName)
Endif
```

If you don't execute your open file dialog, dialog itself is not shown and contained filename is empty!!

**EDITED:**
I edit my post to reflect what you asked in your comment:

```
Dim File_Directory As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
File_Directory.Filename = initial_file_name
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(File_Directory.FileName)
```

or better

```
Dim File_Directory As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(initial_file_name)
```

Comment: İ know but ı want to get inital path and when user select path, objReader is uptade with path ?

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant's comment about *As New* is correct.  You should not create your StreamReader as a global variable.  Don't create it until you are ready to use it.  And in the case of the StreamReader, you should instantiate it inside a Using block:

```
Imports System.IO

Sub Main()

    Dim filename As String = someMethodThatGetsTheFilename()

    Using objReader As New StreamReader(filename)
        'Use the StreamReader here
    End Using   'This line will automatically close and dispose of the StreamReader

End Sub
```

In general, you should try to avoid using global variables and declare them close to where you will be using them.